# Decoding multiple types for the same key

Tags: swift

I have the following structure for a Json:

```
"config": {
    "ids": false,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "value1"
      },
      {
        "name": "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

The issue that I have is that the response can have the following format too:

```
"config": {
    "ids": [
      {
        "id": "id1"
      },
      {
        "id": "id2"
      }
    ],
    "names": false
  }
```

Any suggestion of how can I achieve this?

Current state:

```
struct Config: Decodable, Equatable {
    let names: Names?
}

struct Names: Decodable, Equatable {
    let names: [[String: String]]?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        facets = try container.decode([[String: String]].self, forKey: ???)
    }
}
```

Comment: use a different struct for each configuration type. Right before you serialize the json into the struct, perform some kind of check to see which config the json has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Object Structure**

Try and give the following a go:

```
// MARK: - Config
struct Config: Codable {
    let ids: IDS
    let names: Names
}

enum IDS: Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case idArray([ID])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode([ID].self) {
            self = .idArray(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(IDS.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for IDS"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .bool(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .idArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - ID
struct ID: Codable {
    let id: String
}

enum Names: Codable {
    case bool(Bool)
    case nameArray([Name])

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
            self = .bool(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode([Name].self) {
            self = .nameArray(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Names.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for Names"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .bool(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .nameArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Name
struct Name: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

**How I Did It**

I generated this using [QuickType](https://quicktype.io) which can convert JSON into Swift objects. In order to achieve the following above, I entered the JSON as a list of `Config` options and then just removed the parts I didn't need from the given output...

```
[
    {
        "config": {
        "ids": false,
        "names": [
          {
            "name": "value1"
          },
          {
            "name": "value2"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "config": {
        "ids": [
          {
            "id": "id1"
          },
          {
            "id": "id2"
          }
        ],
        "names": false
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: I struggled with an issue for 2 days before discovering your answer and implementing it. Thank you!!